# How to use sum if value has decimals values - google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheet and i want to count A1:A and then want to multiply with B1

```
    A        B        C
    5.45     3      =A1:A*B1  (16.35)
    5           
    5    
Total = 15.45
```

As show in above sheet in `C` its not show right value. How can i get right value in `C`. 
I want to get 15.45 in `C` but it shows 16.35.

Comment: A1:A returns the first value in the series (5.45), and you're multiplying it by 3, so it is returning 16.35, why would you expect 15.45?

Comment: thanks for helping me understand that returns the first value. im new so misunderstand the function ..

Comment: That's not the full story though, if you enter it as an array formula you get all the numbers in column A multiplied by 3.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks for information .. can you provide array formula so i can try.

Comment: Sure =arrayformula(A1:A*B1)

Comment: @TomSharpe  thanks dear for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you meant to `sum` the `A` column:

```
=SUM(A:A)*B1
```